# Filtering selected categories from a column based on the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

After making a boxplot visualising a categorical feature against my target continuous feature-Price, I want to filter a selection or subset of this categorical feature based on the price as there are a number of outliers.

My categorical feature is airline. So say I want to make a new dataframe where the categories 'Aer Lingus' and 'Ryanair' have a price less than 1000.

How can I select and clamp these categories within airline dependent on price?

```
irish_airlines= ['Aer Lingus','Ryanair']


df['Price'].loc[df['Airline'].isin(irish_airlines) < 1000]
```

doesn't work as it returns a series of all the prices. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Chain both conditions by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df[df['Airline'].isin(irish_airlines) & (df['Price'] < 1000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can 'where' on dataframe

```
filter1 = df['Airline'].isin(['Aer Lingus','Ryanair'])
filter2 = df['Price'] < 1000
df = df.where( filter1 & filter2)
```